# RESTful routing description in zend framework 2 for get(), create(), update(), delete()

Tags: rest, routes, zend-framework2

one more question which is related to RESTful webservice with Zend Framework 2. Surprisingly I am able to get my JSON string when I call http://ehcserver.localhost/rest, so the getList() method is implemented. I thought that I should be able to call http://ehcserver.localhost/rest/id/2 for invoking get(id)-method of RestController. Instead of a JSON script I received a 404 error. I think the routing in my config.php must cause this issue. You can see the code on github: https://github.com/Jochen1980/EhcServer/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php

This is the related routing:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'rest' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/rest',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Rest',
                         ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'default' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/:controller[/:id][/]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'home' => array(
                ...
```

UPDATE: get(id) works now, I changed my configuration to ...

```
'rest' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/rest[/:id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'id' => '[0-9]+',       
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Rest',
        ),
    ),
),
...
```

Comment: I think you have to call http://ehcserver.localhost/rest/2 without `id`, because it's actually coded that way in the route (`:id` is the parameter and there is no need for the `id` name).

Comment: Thanks @Aufziehvogel unfortunately skipping 'id' did not solve this issue. If I call http://ehcserver.localhost/rest/2 I will get a 404 error with the message 'The requested URL could not be matched by routing'.

Comment: Now (see Update to my first post here) get($id) works, the related call is ehcserver.localhost/rest/2

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are using AbstractRestfulController, the following methods are allowed.

GET - get($id) - get the user data
CREATE  create($data) - Create the User data
UPDATE - update($id, $data) - Update the user data
DELETE - delete($id) - Delete the data

```
'tes' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test/showtestpage[:/id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                         ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Tes\Controller\Tes',
                        'action' => null,
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
```

Automatically the URL on the route, points to get($id), create($data), put($id, $data), delete($id) methods in the controller, based on the url made.

Thanks,